# Nginx Error OCSP could not be resolved

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl

I'm getting this error on my Nginx error log:

```
[error] 742#742: ocsp.comodoca.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out) while requesting certificate status, responder: ocsp.comodoca.com, certificate: "/etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt"
```

I'm using Nginx 1.14.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.
This error occurs while i use OCSP stapling. This error occurs about 2 times in 3 days. But, the website [APKGeny.com](https://www.apkgeny.com/) runs well when i open it and when i test it on [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) the status OCSP stapling is active.

Here is my OCSP configuration:

```
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ocsp.ca-bundle;
```

I got the trusted_certificate file from my SSL provider (Namecheap).

So how to fix this? Or maybe just ignore them because my site runs well?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use IPv6? or your nginx compiled both ipv4 and ipv6?

If yes. Most likely reason for the problem you are seeing is broken AAAA address resolution somewhere in your setup. Your nginx is compiled with IPv6 and will try to resolve both A and AAAA addresses, and the message indicate that one of the DNS request (either for A or AAAA records) times out. Source: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/553

I test on ssllabs your OCSP stapling is active.

Comment: Right, i install nginx from apt so ipv4 and ipv6 compiled. And the error just occurs 2 times in 3 days. Not continuously

Comment: as i read on the source above, just ignore them.

Comment: I think I have a similar problem, in that my ocsp (ocsp.sectigo.com) has no AAAA record.  Can I somehow tell nginx to ONLY look for the A record, to stop my error log filling up with these (I get about 20 an hour)

Comment: Additional question:  if my resolver_timeout is set to 10s, does this mean that every time I see that error in my log, a user somewhere had a 10s delay incurred into their browsing of my site?